# Passing Image name or image id attribute when user clicks the image

Tags: javascript, php, html

My requirement is to pass the image name to store.php when user clicked on the image.

Based on the image name i will query database and display the result

But I dont know how to pass the image name when user clicked on it.  Please advise.

Code is as follows :

```
<form action="store.php" method="post">
<div class="col-md-2 about-left">
                    <figure class="effect-bubba">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="images/flip.jpg" id="flipkart" name="flipkart" alt=""/>
                        <figcaption>
                            <h2>FLIPKART</h2>
                        </figcaption>           
                    </figure>
                </div>
</form>
```

Comment: you should use ajax to send image name to php script. you have to write click event for img tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code :-

```
function get_image_name(){
var src = $('img').attr('src').split('/');
var image_name = src[src.length - 1];
alert(image_name);
}
```

call function this function on image `onclick`:-

```
<img class="img-responsive" src="images/flip.jpg" id="flipkart" 
name="flipkart" alt="" onclick="get_image_name()"/>
```

Without javascript try this approach :-

```
<input type="hidden" name="image_name"  value="images/flip.jpg" />
```

insert `hidden input` inside form set value of this same as `src` of image

```
$_POST['image_name'] //get image name
```

Comment: HI Thank you for your reply, i would like to know how it can be done without using javascript, because querying database is my next level of action that too i m doing it with php.  Thanks in advance

Comment: Thank you for your input.  I tried your second suggestion, When i click on image, nothing is happening i am expecting it to redirect to store.php which is not happening.  Please advise

Comment: <button name="button" value="action1"><img class="img-responsive" src="images/flip.jpg" id="flipkart" name="flipkart" alt=""/></button>

Comment: use image tag inside button tag

Comment: Thank you so much i <button type="hidden">
      <input type="hidden" name="imagename" value="flipkart">       
      <img class="img-responsive" src="images/flipkart.jpg" id="flipkart" name="imagename" alt="" onclick="send_image_name()"/>
     </button>

Comment: Working absolutely fine now.  Thank you so much for your kind assitance

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript ajax to send name of the image to php as follows.
Your html is as follows.

```
<img class="img-responsive" src="images/flip.jpg" id="flipkart" 
name="flipkart" alt="" onclick="send_image_name()"/>
```

Javascript should be as follows.

```
function send_image_name(){
var src = $('img').attr('src').split('/');
var image_name = src[src.length - 1];
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
      alert("Successfully sent name!");
    }
  }
  xhttp.open("GET", "store.php?image_name=" + image_name, true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind assistance